# python 'module' object has no attribute 'server_order' error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing python. I have two different python file (client_side.py, server_side.py) call

both script function. After running these script, i got this error.

```
'module' object has no attribute 'server_order' error
```

**1. Server_side.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import client_side

username = "xxxxxx"
password = "123"
filename = "dfsdf.txt"
client_side.client(username,password,filename)

def server_order():
    print "server side is running."
    return
```

**2. client_side.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def client(a,b,c):
    print "client side function processing.."
    client_order()
    if __name__ == '__client__':
        client()
        return 

def client_order():
    import server_side
    server_side.server_order()
    return
```

Comment: Are client_side and server_side in the same folder?

Comment: @Aswin. yes, both files are in same folder.

Comment: May be the problem is because of the circular dependency

Comment: @Aswin. I don't know about circular dependency how is solve it?

Comment: server_side imports client_side and the function in the client_side imports server_side.. This is the circular dependency. Try removing that

Comment: How to do that depends on your code

Comment: @Aswin. I don't know how to do.

Comment: has server_side the first letter uppercase ? (as you describe as name of the first file)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order you are defining the functions.  You must define the functions before you import them, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import client_side

username = "xxxxxx"
password = "123"
filename = "dfsdf.txt"

def server_order():
    print "server side is running."
    return 

client_side.client(username,password,filename)
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def client_order():
    import server_side
    server_side.server_order()
    return

def client(a,b,c):
    print "client side function processing.."
    client_order()
    if __name__ == '__client__':
        client()
        return
```

Your initial problem was that `client_side.client()` was being called before you defined `server_order()`.  Therefore when `client_side.client()` tried to call it, it was not there!